# How to position lines at the edges of stacked bar charts

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to change the position of lines, such that they start and end at the edges of stacked bar charts instead of in the center?

R code:

```
library(ggplot2)
plot11 = ggplot(CombinedThickness2[CombinedThickness2$DepSequence == "Original",], aes(x = Well, y = Thickness, fill = Sequence, alpha = Visible, width = 0.3)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_reverse() 
plot11 = plot11 + geom_line(aes(group = Sequence, y = Depth, color = Sequence))
plot11
```

Current image:

[image: enter link description here]

Data:

http://pastebin.com/D7uSKBmA

Comment: So it looks similar to this: http://2012books.lardbucket.org/books/using-microsoft-excel-v1.1/section_08/498259105d99351b2b2d43c2a1a1d2ca.jpg

Comment: Welcome to SO! By edges you mean top edges, bottom ones or both?

Comment: Thanks :) I mean both @tonytonov

Answer (score 1):

It seems that what is required is segments rather than lines; that is, use  `geom_segment()` in place of `geom_line()`. `geom_segment` requires x and y coordinates for the start and end points of the segments. Getting the end y value is a bit unwieldy. But it works with your data frame assuming that there are 30 observations for each "Well", and that the order for "Sequence" is the same for each "Well".

```
library(ggplot2)

df = CombinedThickness2[CombinedThickness2$DepSequence == "Original",]

# Get the y end values
index = 1:dim(df)[1]
NWell = length(unique(df$Well))
df$DepthEnd[index] = df$Depth[index + dim(df)[1]/NWell]

BarWidth = 0.3

plot11 = ggplot(df, 
   aes(x = Well, y = Thickness, fill = Sequence, alpha = Visible)) + 
   geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = BarWidth) +
   scale_y_reverse() + scale_alpha(guide = "none") 

plot11 = plot11 + 
   geom_segment(aes(x = as.numeric(Well) + 0.5*BarWidth, xend = as.numeric(Well) + (1-0.5*BarWidth), 
      y = Depth, yend = DepthEnd, color = Sequence)) 

plot11
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The amount of observations for each well is not the same, but it still seems like it works. When I try to do this I get the bars but no lines. And I get a bunch of warning messages, one of them is: 'In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : NAs introduced by coercion', but most of them are: 'In loop_apply(n, do.ply) : Removed 3 rows containing missing values (geom_segment).' I am obviously a bit of a newbie to R, but it seems to run smoothly with the exception of the missing segments. Any suggestions for improvement?

Comment: Apologies for the delay. I'm not sure why you are getting these warnings and errors. I don't. With regard to the data you provided, for `DepSequence == "Original"`, I get 30 observations per "Well", and the order for "Sequence" remains the same within each "Well". I tried selecting a few other "DepSequences" - the same applies. In each case, the `geom_segment` chart and the `geom_line` chart produced the same lines; the only difference is that in the `geom_segment` chart, the lines begin and end at the edge of the stacked bars.